# Zlib Inflation stream not set to Z_STREAM_END at end of PNG IDAT data

Tags: c++, png, zlib

I am trying to write my own PNG decoder for learning purposes. The code I'm using to decompress the data is below:

```
//Stores the return code from the inflation stream
int returnCode;

//Tracks amount of data inflated
unsigned int dataReturned;

//Inflation stream
z_stream stream;

//Initalising the inflation state
stream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
stream.zfree = Z_NULL;
stream.opaque = Z_NULL;
stream.avail_in = chunkSize;
stream.next_in = compressedPixelData;

//Beginning the inflation stream

cout << "Beginning inflation" << endl;
returnCode = inflateInit(&stream);

//Checks for any errors with the inflation stream
if (returnCode != Z_OK)
    throw invalid_argument("Provided file is corrupted or does not use deflate as its compression algorithm");

//Pointing the stream to the output array
stream.avail_out = chunkSize;
stream.next_out = pixelData;

//Inflating the data
returnCode = inflate(&stream, Z_NO_FLUSH);

//Checking for errors
switch (returnCode) {

case Z_NEED_DICT:
case Z_DATA_ERROR:
case Z_MEM_ERROR:
    throw runtime_error("Error while decompressing pixel data. Either out of memory or the file is corrupted.");

}

dataReturned = chunkSize - stream.avail_out;
cout << dataReturned << endl;

//Ending the deflation stream and cleaning up

cout << "Return Code: " << returnCode << endl;
(void)inflateEnd(&stream);
delete[] compressedPixelData;
```

I get Z_OK as the return code at the end of inflating the chunk. I've double checked and there is only one IDAT chunk in the file, `chunkSize` is the size of the chunk taken from the header of the chunk, and both `compressedPixelData` and `pixelData` are both char arrays allocated with `chunkSize` bytes of memory. `pixelData` contains the entire contents of the IDAT chunk (excluding the CRC checksum).

Why is the return code still `Z_OK` instead of `Z_STREAM_END`, once the entire IDAT chunk has been inflated?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Constants), `Z_STREAM_END` is not an error, and as valid as `Z_OK`. Error codes are negative, these two are not.

Comment: Are you sure you're allocating enough space in in `pixelData`/`stream.next_out` and setting `stream.avail_out` to the right size? Or did that space get filled up by the one inflate call before decompressing all the data? Setting both `stream.avail_in` and `stream.avail_out` to the same value is strange.

Comment: @Shawn My understanding is that `stream.avail_in` is the number of bytes available to be decompressed, and `stream.avail_out` is the available space in the output buffer. Since I've set the output buffer to the same size as the full input buffer they are both the same value.

Comment: @usr2564301 I know `Z_STREAM_END` is not an error state. It signifies the end of the stream of data to inflate. Since I've passed in all the data, I'm expecting to get `Z_STREAM_END` back, but instead I'm getting `Z_OK`.

Comment: The output size is normally *larger* than the input size when decompressing, though... If you're using the same size there's still data left to decompress that there isn't room for in the output buffer you're using, hence `Z_OK`.

Comment: @Shawn Excellent point, I'm an idiot, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Shawn, the decompressed data is larger than the original input data. Increasing the size of `stream.avali_out` and the output buffer, `pixelData` fixed the issue.